# What is the difference between NPM -g (global) install and NPM --save

Tags: npm, gulp

What is the difference between `npm -g(global)` install and `npm --save`?

First `gulp install -g` and `--save` first, then for other projects:
 `npm i gulp --save-dev` Can I just use this command?
I don't know the basic difference between them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`npm -g` will install packages globally (to npm cached folder), normally in `AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules` if you're using Windows, while `npm --save` or `--save-dev` will install package directly to your node_modules directory in your project and add package to your packages.json for later purpose.